# How to open a file in a maximized window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have an XML file that I want to open in a maximized window. I have configured Windows to open all XML files with an XML program that is installed. Currently when I double-click the file in Explorer it opens in a non-maximized window. I tried configuring the shortcut of the XML program to open maximized, but this seems to only work when I click the shortcut, and not a specific XML file.

Comment: You can always drag and drop the file into the program if it supports that operation.

Comment: Which program are you using to open XML files with?

Comment: I'm using Xml Viewer by MindFusion